# Problem with lualatex, TeXGyre Pagella Math and mathbf

Tags: fonts, luatex

With the next code I get:

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/TeXGyrePagella(1)/bx/n' undefined
>   (Font) using`TU/TeXGyrePagella(1)/m/n'
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults
>   substituted.

How to avoid these warnings?
At the moment my only solution is not to use `TeX Gyre Pagella`

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[ Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\begin{document}
    $\mathbf{R}^2$    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which release of `fontspec` do you have?

Comment: I have 2.7h and I'm in the process of updating

Comment: @JosephWright The problem just disappears with the last version ! thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The warning appears with `fontspec` version 2.7h, but disappears with version 2.7i (just downloaded).

However, you should be using `\symbf{R}`.

Comment: I don't know the macro `symbf`. Is this part of a unicode-math ?

Comment: @AlainMatthes Yes, since a couple of years, IIRC

Answer (score 3):

You probably want `\symbfup` or `\symbfit` to get individual bold letters in math mode.

In `unicode-math`, `\mathbf` and `\mathrm` are intended more for complete words, such as `\frac{\mathrm{RISE}}{\mathrm{RUN}}`.

If you want to denote the Euclidean space ℝ², a good alternative is to use the blackboard letter `\symbb{R}` or, for compatibility, `\mathbb{R}`.

Comment: Thanks, it's very useful as a complement